# Prove that $\frac{1}{a+ab}+\frac{1}{b+bc}+\frac{1}{c+ca} \geq \frac{3}{2}.$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,$ and $c$ be positive real numbers such that $abc = 1$. Prove that $$\dfrac{1}{a+ab}+\dfrac{1}{b+bc}+\dfrac{1}{c+ca} \geq \dfrac{3}{2}.$$

I thought about substituting in $abc = 1$ to get $$\dfrac{1}{a+\dfrac{1}{c}}+\dfrac{1}{b+\dfrac{1}{a}}+\dfrac{1}{c+\dfrac{1}{b}} = \dfrac{c}{ac+1}+\dfrac{a}{ab+1}+\dfrac{b}{bc+1}.$$ Then I am not sure what inequality to apply.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the inequality is equivalent to

$(abc+1)(\frac{1}{a(1+b)}+\frac{1}{b(1+c)}+\frac{1}{c(1+a)})+3\ge 6$

This is equivalent to proving that

$\frac{1+abc+a+ab}{a(1+b)}+\frac{1+abc+b+bc}{b(1+c)}+\frac{1+abc+c+ca}{c(1+a)}\ge6$.

However, $\frac{1+abc+a+ab}{a(1+b)}+\frac{1+abc+b+bc}{b(1+c)}+\frac{1+abc+c+ca}{c(1+a)}=\frac{1+a}{a(1+b)}+\frac{1+b}{b(1+c)}+\frac{1+c}{c(1+a)}+\frac{b(c+1)}{b+1}+\frac{c(a+1)}{c+1}+\frac{a(b+1)}{a+1} \ge 6 (\because AM-GM)$.

Therefore, our proof is done.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=\frac{x}{y}$, $b=\frac{y}{z}$, $c=\frac{z}{x}$.

$$\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{1}{\frac{x}{y}+\frac{x}{y}\frac{y}{z}}=\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{yz}{xz+xy}$$

Let $yz=c$, $xz=d$, $xy=e$. Then your inequality follows from [Nesbitt's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt%27s_inequality).