# How would you prove $\frac{1}{xz+x}+\frac{1}{xy+y}+\frac{1}{zy+z} \geq \frac{3}{2}$?

Tags: inequality

If $x$, $y$, $z$ are integers with $xyz=1$, $\frac{1}{xz+x}+\frac{1}{xy+y}+\frac{1}{zy+z} 
\geq \frac{3}{2}$ any suggestions to proceed?

I think would be fine to work them out separately. Thanks

Comment: take $x = y = z = 2$

Comment: Some essential conitions are missing, please edit.

Comment: Yes, I think they gave me the incorrect exercise, sorry for that it's true

Comment: Are they supposed to be positive integers otherwise if negative integers are considered then the inequality is incorrect. For example try taking x= -2 , y=1, z= 1.

Comment: Perhaps you meant this [Prove that $\frac{1}{a+ab}+\frac{1}{b+bc}+\frac{1}{c+ca} \geq \frac{3}{2}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1612842/42969)? – It holds if $a, b, c$ are positive with $abc=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can disprove it for example of they all = 3.